# How to bind action/wizard into specific model via python method in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

AFAIK, if i want to bind action/wizard to a model, then i have to write this line code in xml, e.g:

```
<act_window name="New Sub menu"
    res_model="action.product"
    src_model="product.product"
    key2="client_action_multi" 
    view_mode="form" target="new" 
    view_type="form"
    id="act_new_sub_menu" />
```

And obviously I have to restart the server to make this change available.

But, can I trigger another method via python to bind specific action/wizard into specific model in odoo? so i dont have to restart the server to make those action/wizard available

> Note : we can assume the action/wizard model (action.product) has been implemented and
>   fully loaded. I just want to bind this same action into another
>   model (e.g. project.task) via python method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now i get it.!
we just have to register the existing action/wizard to existing another model in ir.values. In another words, i just have to create ir.values in python method,

e.g: if i want to bind wizard 'action.product' to model project.task, i just need to write this line of code :

```
self.env['ir.values'].create(
{'key': 'action',
'key2': 'client_action_multi',
'model': 'project.task',
'res_id': 0,
'name': 'act_new_sub_menu',
'value': 'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(self.env['ir.actions.act_window'].search([('name', '=', 'New Sub menu')]).ids[0]),
})
```

hope, this help you too.